# Losing session variables after redirect

Tags: php, session

1. User fills in username and password.
2. If it's correct, the page loads some information such as `user_id` to a session variable.
3. The script makes a `header('Location')` redirect.
4. Somehow the next page doesn't recognize the session... how come?

The redirection is to the same domain, and all pages have `session_start();`

And I found it more likely to happen in IE than in FF... strange.

Comment: could you post some code?

Answer (score 7):

Is it possible that cookies aren't enabled?

In order to be able to associate session variables with a specific client instance (ie. how session variables can be used on your browser and my browser at the same time without getting into a conflict), a "session ID" (or "SID") is generated per session. This ID is stored on the server, as well as on the client, usually in the form of a cookie. However, if cookies are not enabled, the session ID is passed along as part of the query string of the URL in each request so that the server can know what session ID belongs to the client.

When you redirect by a `header()` call, PHP does not automatically insert the SID into the new request, so you will need to append it yourself, in the form of:

```
header("Location: my_url.com/my_page.php?" . SID)
```

where [`SID`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.constants.php) is a constant defined by PHP that contains the necessary part of the query string (equivalent to `session_name() . '='  . session_id()`, if a session ID exists).

See [Passing the Session ID](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Can you explain me a bit?  what did meen by "propagating the SID"? If this put any more light - just found out that in the localhost it works fine, but on the server something goes wrong.

Comment: you are very clear. Thank you for your help. Unfortunately it didn't help and my cookies are enabled, and as I said, on the localhost it works great.
Still I can't figure what causing it to dump the session. 
Is there another way of making redirect in PHP without having the trouble of loosing session variables ?

Thank you!

Comment: I knocked my head against the wall until I checked if my cookies were enabled. Thanks for the hint1

Answer (score 5):

I just had a similar issue, the solution was to simply add an *exit();* instruction under the *header(..)* redirection.

Answer (score 2):

Two thoughts:

1. Is session_start() located at the top of the scripts, before anything is sent to the browser?
2. Is the domain exactly the same? www.mydomain.com re-directing to mydomain.com would lead to the problem you describe.

Comment: i have the second case, i have to redirect to a subdomain how can a deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location: my_url.com/my_page.php?" . SID)
exit();
```

It only worked after I added `exit()` below the `header();`

Comment: hello, i may think wrong but if PHP is a line-by-line interpreter how will be executed the exit() if the url is redirected, and dont return back?

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress documentation states that cookies will be cleared if the user's password is changed. That will kill the session, regardless of whether a redirect happens. So long as you can prevent the cookies from being cleared (and an `exit()` may do that, as suggested in other answers) than the session should remain.

> Note: If current user's password is being updated, then the cookies
>   will be cleared!

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today and have been searching for a way to fix it. I already had what everyone else has mentioned and could not find an answer anywhere.

Eventually I found the answer after watching my session variables with `Firebug`. I noticed that on the pages that the variables were being lost, the session `Parameter:secure` was being set to `true` for some reason unknown to me.

**The fix** was to **set the `secure` parameter to false** before the session was created.

I accomplished this using `session_set_cookie_params`. Something like this:

```
session_set_cookie_params([lifetime], [path], [domain], false, true);
```