# CakePHP Session lost after OAuth redirect

Tags: cakephp

I'm having almost the identical problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079477/session-is-lost-after-an-oauth-redirect). Unfortunately this question provides no solutions. I'm using strictly HTTPS and still have the problem. I've tried all I can think of: Session.checkAgent=false, Session.cookieTimeout=0, Security.level=low, etc. I cannot re-produce the problem in any way, however, a small portion of our customers are complaining that their session is being lost. I don't know any way to debug and/or determine how/where the session is being destroyed. I don't know what else to do, can anyone help? I'm using CakePHP 2.4.5 and can upgrade to 2.5.5, but would like to determine what the issue is so I can have peace of mind that it has been fixed.

Comment: Is the web server configured properly to read/write session files? Have you tried storing the session data in a MySQL database instead of files?

Comment: tell them to enable cookie in their browser, Cookie must be enabled to use the session

Comment: Sessions are being written properly to the server and the end users have cookies enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

`Configure::write('Session.referer_check' ,false);`

But before putting that into production, you should know how it may affect your security.

The only real way to fix this is if you can reproduce it.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation on Session.referer_check. Where would I find that? My understanding is Session.checkAgent is supposed to do essentially what is inferred here: check the referer user agent and allow/deny accordingly.